# Editing languages in siteadmin/preferences in AEM

Tags: aem, momentjs, iso

I am trying to change the list of languages in the Admin preferences. I referred to this page: http://www.wemblog.com/2012/06/how-to-add-new-supported-language-in-cq.html
I am able to get the list of languages but each time I get languages like Arabic or Amharic (which are not there in libs) I get the following error in the `moment.js` file.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postformat' of null

This is only there in Touch UI mode. In Classic mode it is not showing any error.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?